# use of undeclared identifier for private variables within a class (C++)

Tags: c++, tostring

I'm trying to use the `std::to_string()` function on private variables within the class, but I'm getting an "undeclared variables" error.

Here is the header file with the function declarations:

```
class Auto_Part
{
public:
    Auto_Part();
    Auto_Part(std::string t, std::string n, int pn, double p): type(t), name(n), part_number(pn), price(p) {};
    std::string get_type() const;
    std::string get_name() const;
    int get_part_number() const;
    double get_price() const;
    void set_type(std::string);
    void set_name(std::string);
    void set_part_number(int);
    void set_price(double);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Auto_Part&);
    bool operator<(const Auto_Part&) const;
    std::string to_string();

private:
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    int part_number;
    double price;
};
```

And here is the function in question in my .cpp file:

```
std::string to_string(){
    return std::to_string(type) + ", " + std::to_string(name) + ", " + std::to_string(part_number) + ", " + std::to_string(price);
}
```

My IDE is highlighting type, name, part_number and price in my to_string() function with the above mentioned error. **Why would it not recognize the variables if they are declared in the class?**

Comment: Do you know you're trying to call `std::to_string` on two member variables that are already `std::string`?

Comment: Good call. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace (which is your `Auto_Part` class) in the definition of `to_string` in your .cpp file. So your code should be

```
std::string Auto_Part::to_string(){
    return std::to_string(type) + ", " + std::to_string(name) + ", " + std::to_string(part_number) + ", " + std::to_string(price);
}
```

Comment: namespace should be class name.  All class members are scoped to the class name.

Comment: Thank you. So you have to do this for every function, even though you are defining it within the class itself?

Comment: No, if you define it inline (that is, in the .h file) you don't need to do this. It is needed only in the .cpp file